# Clicking URLS opens a new tab in FireFox

Tags: firefox, trackpad

I'm running 10.04, with FireFox 3.6.x. I have NoScript and AdBlock installed, as well as Firebug and the GWT toolkit. The problem I'm having is that sometimes URLS open in new tabs even just with a normal click. I use my laptop's built-in trackpad as a pointing device with 'tap to click' enabled. This seems to happen between 10 and 25% of the time. It's quite annoying. Anyone have any idea what causes this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you tapping close to an edge or corner by any chance? Depending on your hardware model and software configuration, tapping near some edges emulates the second (middle) or third (right) mouse button. In Firefox, by default, middle-clicking on a link opens it in a new tab.

Comment: Where would I find settings for middle-click emulation, etc? Hardware is an HP G61 ... I don't recall seeing any configuration in the mouse/trackpad settings. It would be very cool, but I haven't seen this.

Comment: After playing around a bit, it seems that the very bottom of the scroll area is right-click and the top of it is middle-click. Awesome.

Comment: @Nerdfest: A majority of laptops have a [Synaptics touchpad](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad).

Answer (score 2):

When I access my computer over VNC from my phone sometimes I find that the Control key gets sent a lot of the time. I know it's a different use-case to yours but it could be that your control key is getting stuck (or you're accidentally pressing it - I know how easy that can be on some small keyboards).

You might be able to test this by running `xev` and seeing what keys get sent when you click. It throws a lot of output so it might be easiest writing it to a log `xev > ~/Desktop/xev.output` clicking the mousebox a few dozen times like you would click a link and then searching the output for whatever the control key looks like (it might make sense to press the control keys a few times to see what their output looks like for comparison)

Either that or the links are have the attribute `target="_blank"` set.. In which case they're supposed to spawn new windows or tabs. I believe there is an addon that disables this.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you solved this problem. If not, it appears to be a problem with touchpads that has a solution: [at Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/636720)
Hope it helps.

Comment: Your first sentence is unnecessary, OP commented on the accepted answer that the problem is solved.

Comment: Being nice is **not** unnecesary. It has been some time since the question was posted, and even with an accepted answer, it does tell that it was a complete solution. Because i found the question looking for an answer, when i found an specific and technically exact answer I just commented that. I see no point in your words, and see no problem to point to what i consider a more exact answer.

Comment: The comment was not to offend you but to hint on removing it since it's not part of the answer. Thank you for the contribution, it might help others which face similar issues which cannot be solved by the accepted one :)