# Firefox opens new window instead of link

Tags: firefox

So a few days ago I downloaded Firefox Developer Edition (v58 then) in a home folder and executed it from there directly. I created a .desktop file to have a launcher, which pointed to the executable in the appropriate home folder, and when I opened for the first time it prompted me to make it the default browser, so I did - Firefox from repos is also installed, but I planned to stop using it and start using developer edition instead.

So the problem is the following. I have set that when Firefox opens up - that is, when I first open it after I open my pc- a number of urls are opened in tabs - let's think of them as "Starting page tabs".

Suppose I have some messenger app open - not in firefox, a seperate app. Signal Messenger, Discord, Skype for Linux etc.

When someone sent me a link to open, when I clicked on it to open it what happened was that a new tab with the url opened in an already open firefox window. And that was the desired action. That was the case, while I was using Firefox stable version.

When I started using Firefox Developer Edition, and set it as default browser, that is not the case any more. Every time I try to open a URL sent in an outside messenger application, what happens is that the sites I have set as "Starting page tabs" open up inside an already open Firefox window, and the url I wanted to go to is not opened at all.

The system is Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/4919/clicking-urls-opens-a-new-tab-in-firefox?rq=1

Comment: I should be clear. The link is opened in applications outside firefox. While using stable version, that resulted in just a tab opening in an open firefox window.

Comment: The link is opened from* applications outside firefox. Updated the question.

Comment: You should expect bugs and/or glitches in software versions which are still under development. Instead of asking here you should file a bug-report against firefox.

Comment: I asked here, because opening a link equals calling the executable of the default browser with certain parameters, so it might as well just be that I need to add something somewhere to make the browser be called with correct parameters. I will also file a bug in Mozilla as you suggested, nonetheless.

Comment: see also [Link clicked not passed to firefox](https://askubuntu.com/q/41010/539924)

Comment: In my case, Slack opened links in new Firefox windows no matter what I tried. Then I uninstalled Slack as a snap package, and installed it as an apt package instead, that fixed the issue. My theory is snap is so contained, it cannot tap into existing processes <-- but I really don't know what I'm talking about : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, my `.desktop` file was incomplete. To make sure it works, I copied the stable Firefox `.desktop` file, and changed it so that the `Exec` lines pointed to the Developer's edition executable and the `Icon` clause pointed to Developer's edition icon. Also changed the launcher name wherever needed - for English language only though. Now the links work as intended.